# ARM cortex-A7 - cycle interrupts

Tags: interrupts, cortex-a

I'm using a Banana Pi M3 with an ARM cortex-A7.
I want to perform a task in a cycle with a fixed period with no delays and I was wandering if I could use an interrupt for that.
Does this processor even have a cycle interrupt? If so, how can I use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the timer and timer interrupt. But Banana usually is not used as a bare metal development board and it is run under linux which is not good for the RT tasks. If you need the RT functionality - you will need to apply the RT patch to your kernel.